# MySQL grouping when using a sub query

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I am trying to create a summary output to show a totals  based on values in sub queries and then group the output by a label

Query looks like:

```
select c.name,
(select sum(duration) from dates d 
inner join time t1 on d.time_id=t1.id 
where d.employee=t.employee 
and d.date >= now() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH) as ad,    
(select sum(cost) from dates d 
inner join time t1 on d.time_id=t1.id 
where d.employee=t.employee 
and d.date >= now() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH) as ac

FROM time t

inner join employees ee on t.employee=ee.employee
inner join centres c on ee.centre=c.id 
where 
ee.centre in (4792,4804,4834) group by c.centre
```

I want this to show me the ad and ac for each centre but instead it only shows values for ac for the last centre in the list and the rest show as zero

If I remove the group by then I get a list of all the entries but then it is not summarised in any way and I need that rollup view

Comment: Probably learn to format your code properly, and learn to use proper `GROUP BY`.  Your code won't even run in other dbms.  Even newer version of `MySQL` will not run your code.

Comment: seems like you'd want to include joins to `employees` and `centres` in the subqueries, if the goal is to get a total by `centre`. Without example data and sample output, all we have to go on is SQL that is returning a result that is unexpected. Without a specification, we're only guessing at the requirements, and any SQL changes we might propose are just a guess.

Comment: i think the crux of the issue is that the `GROUP BY` is collapsing rows, and the collapsed set includes rows with various values of `t.employee`. A MySQL-specific non-standard extension allows the query to run without throwing an error; that same extension is getting just a single value for `t.employee` for the collapsed set, and that is the value being passed into the subquery in the SELECT list. But (again) without a specification, we're just guessing what this query is supposed to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL statement that is returning a result that is unexpected is not a whole lot to go on.

Without a specification, helpfully illustrated with sample data and expected output, we're just guessing at the result that the query is supposed to achieve.

I think the crux of the problem is the value of `t.employee` returned for the `GROUP BY`, multiple detail rows with a variety of values for `t.employee` are getting collapsed into a single row for each value of `c.centre`, and the value of `t.employee` is from "some row" in the set. (A MySQL-specific non-standard extension allows the query to run without throwing an error, where other RDBMS would throw an error. We can get MySQL behavior more inline with the standard by including `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in `sql_mode. But that would just cause the SQL in the question to throw an error.)

Suggested fix (just a guess) is to derived `ac` and `ad` for each employee, before doing the `GROUP BY`, and then aggregating.

(I'm still suspicious of the joins to `centre`, not being included in the subqueries. Is `employee` the primary key or a unique key in `employees`? Is `centre` functionally dependent on `employee`? So many questions, too many assumptions.

My guess is that we are after the result returned by a query something like this:

```
SELECT c.name
     , SUM(v.ad) AS `ad`
     , SUM(v.ac) AS `ac`
  FROM ( -- derive `ad` and `ac` in an inline view before we collapse rows 
         SELECT ee.employee
              , ee.centre
              , ( -- derived for each employee
                  SELECT SUM(d1.duration)
                    FROM time t1
                    JOIN dates d1
                      ON d1.time_id = t1.id
                     AND d1.date >= NOW() + INTERVAL -12 MONTH
                   WHERE d1.employee = t.employee
                ) AS `ad`
              , ( -- derived for each employee
                  SELECT SUM(d2.cost)
                    FROM time t2
                    JOIN dates d2
                      ON d2.time_id = t2.id
                     AND d2.date >= NOW() + INTERVAL -12 MONTH
                   WHERE d2.employee = t.employee
                ) AS `ac`
           FROM time t
           JOIN employees ee
             ON ee.employee = t.employee
          WHERE ee.centre in (4792,4804,4834)
          GROUP
             BY ee.employee
              , ee.centre
      ) v
 LEFT
 JOIN centres c
   ON c.id = v.centre
GROUP
   BY v.centre
    , c.name
```